# GitlabCI delayed job depending on one of two jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` :

```
stages:
 - Stage1
 - Stage2

# Stage1
Job1:
  stage: Stage1
  script:
    - doSomething

Job2:
  stage: Stage1
  script:
    - doSomething

# Stage2
Job3:
  stage: Stage2
  script:
    - doSomething
  when: delayed
  start_in: 2 hours
```

I would like to schedule Job3 only if one of [Job1, Job2] succeeds. I don't need both to succeed, just one of the two.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have the same question. I don't see the answer in any of their documentation. What I'm thinking on is adding `allow_failure: false` to Job1 and Job2 to make sure the pipeline stops and Job3 will not run